# Find multi-dimensional binding more efficient way

Tags: python, algorithm, binning

I am trying to find multi-dimensional binding. This is the code which I have so far. Is there some way to do it more efficient?

```
a = np.random.random((3000,3000)) 

def flinspace(a, b, n, endpoint=True):
    a, b = np.asanyarray(a), np.asanyarray(b)
return a[..., None] + (b-a)[..., None]/(n-endpoint) * np.arange(n)

@jit
def fdigitize(x,q,axis=0):
    x = np.asanyarray(x).copy()
    f,l = np.nanmin(x,axis=axis),np.nanmax(x,axis=axis)
    y = flinspace(f,l,q)
    for i in range(x.shape[1]):
        mask = ~np.isnan(x[:,i]);x[:,i][mask] = np.digitize(x[:,i][mask], y[i])-1
    return x 

%timeit xx = fdigitize(a,100)
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to apply linear transformations to the columns of x, mapping them to `[0, q-1]`. Then simply run a `np.floor` to get their bins. 
(This gives slightly different solutions than your algorithm for the max-values, where your algorithm is inconsistent about wheter the max-element of each column should belong to bin `q-1` or `q-2`)

```
def fdigitizeadj(x, q, axis=0):
    x = np.asanyarray(x)
    f = np.nanmin(x, axis=axis)
    l = np.nanmax(x, axis=axis)
    adj = (q-1)*(x-f)/(l-f)  # Linear transformation here
    return np.floor(adj)
```

(At least compared to the un-jitted code this gives a speedup and runs your example in 113ms)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is very useful to me, originally I would like to solve outside the loop